# Phone Book Program in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, homework

I am starting out a school project to build a phone book program in C++. It stores contacts in a linked list. This currently does not have all the validations I would like to implement, and is all in one `phonebook.cpp` file. I am required to implement a linked list as part of the assignment. Any constructive feedback would be appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    node *next;
};

class List
{
private:
    node *head, *tail;
public:
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    void create_contact(string first, string last) // Create node and add it onto the linked list
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->firstName = first;
        temp->lastName = last;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }

    void display_all() // Prints out current trip
    {
        int contactNum = 1;
        node *temp = new node;
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)    // Loop through the list while the temporary node is not empty
        {
            cout << "\nContact Number: " << contactNum << endl;
            cout << "First Name: " << temp->firstName << endl;
            cout << "Last Name: " << temp->lastName << endl;
            ++contactNum;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void delete_position(int pos)   // delete a stop by using the position in the list
    {
        node *current = new node;
        node *previous = new node;
        node *next = new node;
        current = head;
        for (int i = 1;i<pos;i++)   // Loop through the link list while the current node is not empty
        {
            if (current == NULL)
                return;
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        next = current->next;
        previous->next = current->next;
        delete current;
    }

    void delete_head()  // delete head node
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    List Contacts; // create a Contacts item for the List class
    int choice, position;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;

    while (1) {
        cout << "\nWhat would you like to do?: " << endl;
        cout << "1. Show All Contacts" << endl;
        cout << "2. Add A Contact" << endl;
        cout << "3. Remove A Contact" << endl;
        cout << "4. Search Contacts (Coming Soon)" << endl;
        cout << "5. Exit The Program" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << endl;
            Contacts.display_all(); // display all contacts
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "\nEnter your first name: ";
            cin >> firstName;
            cout << "\nEnter your last name: ";
            cin >> lastName;
            Contacts.create_contact(firstName, lastName); // create the contact in the linked list
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Enter the contact number of the contact you would like to remove: ";
            cin >> position;
            if (position == 1)
                Contacts.delete_head();
            else
                Contacts.delete_position(position); // delete contact from list
            break;
        case 5:
            exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\n" << choice << " is not an option. Please select a valid option." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it wasn't required my first point would be that a linked-list is the wrong data type. Accessing people at the end of the list takes much longer than those at the front. If you needed to keep a sorted list a `std::vector` would be a much more performant choice. Otherwise, a phone book is designed to associate names with numbers and therefore a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` seems like the right choice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a number of things that could be improved, and I hope you find this list of suggestions useful.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Don't use `system("pause")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `PAUSE` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example:

```
void pause() {
    getchar();
}
```

### General portability

This code *could* be made portable if, in addition to the changes in the previous point, you omit the Windows-only include files `#include "stdafx.h"`.

### Name things consistently

We have `node` and then `List`, with an uppercase initial letter.  It's usually better to name things consistently so that readers of the code (including you!) will have an easier time understanding it.

### Use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`

Modern C++ uses `nullptr` rather than `NULL`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr/1283623#1283623) for why and how it's useful.

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference betweeen `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

### Don't leak memory

In the `delete_position` code, we have this line:

```
node *next = new node;
```

However, that `next` is never `delete`d and is assigned but not otherwise usefully used in the program.  The code for this should be refactored.

### Understand pointers

In several cases the code does something like this:

```
node *temp = new node;
```

However, `new` allocates memory and actually creates a new node.  What's probably actually needed in most cases is just a pointer.  For example, the `display_all` function could be written instead like this:

```
void display_all() const 
{
    int contactNum = 0;
    for (node *curr = head; curr; curr = curr->next) 
    {
        std::cout << "\nContact Number: " << ++contactNum << "\n";
        std::cout << "First Name: " << curr->firstName << "\n";
        std::cout << "Last Name: " << curr->lastName << "\n";
    }
}
```

### Use const where practical

Functions such as `display_all` which do not alter the underlying `List` should be declared `const`.  In general, whenever you are writing a variable or function prototype look for places you can use `const`.

### Prefer modern initializers for constructors

The code currently has this constructor:

```
List()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}
```

I'd advocate using the more modern C++11 style:

```
List() :
    head{nullptr},
    tail{nullptr}
{}
```

### Perform better error checking for user input

As it is currently written, if the user types "Norway" as the `choice` the code will loop endlessly.  Better would be to input a `string` and then use `std::stoi` to convert it to a number.

### Keep private data private

Outside the `List`, there is no need to have a `node`, so I would recommend that the `node` definition should be a `private` definition within `List`.

### Keep implementation details private

Don't require the user of the `List` class to call `delete_head` or `delete_position` depending on which node it is.  Instead, have a single `delete_position` the does the right thing for either.

### Simplify deletion of nodes

Here's an alternative method for deleting a node that doesn't leak memory and incorporates the previous suggestion.

```
void delete_position(int pos)    
{
    if (pos < 1 || head == nullptr) 
        return;
    node *victim{head};
    if (pos == 1) {  // deleting head
        if (tail == victim) {
            head = tail = nullptr;
        } else {
            head = head->next;
        }
    } else { 
        // deleting non-head node
        node *prev{head};
        for (pos -= 2; pos; --pos) {
            if (prev == nullptr)
                return;
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        victim = prev->next;
        prev->next = victim->next;
        if (tail == victim) {
            tail = prev;
        }
    }
    delete victim;
}
```

### Provide a destructor

Because the class allocates memory, it should include a destructor to free any memory that might have been allocated.

Comment: It would be great if we could box some content in other colors. Your general portability points would be a great fit.

Answer (score 5):

### [Avoid `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3964927)

This can cause name collisions because it adds every name in the `std` namespace to the global namespace. For a small program like this one it's unlikely that you'll run into any problems (then again, [maybe not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593548/3964927)) but it's best to get into the habit of using the `std::` prefix on names in the `std` namespace.

Alternatively, you can introduce [using declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) like `using std::cout;` to add specific names to the global namespace.

### Avoid `std::endl` in favor of `\n`

[`std::endl` flushes the stream, which can cause a loss in performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/3964927)

### Don't reinvent the wheel

Since you've tagged this homework you may be required to implement a linked list as part of the assignment. If not, however, you can use [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) with your `node` struct or something similar as the data type for the `std::list` (you'd be able to remove the `node *next` field of the `node` struct).

Here's a basic demo of what such a contacts list would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

struct Name {
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
};

class Contacts {
private:
    std::list<Name> contacts;
public:
    void add(Name name) {
        contacts.push_back(name);
    }

    void add(std::string first, std::string last) {
        contacts.push_back(Name{first, last});
    }

    void display() {
        for (auto name : contacts) {
            std::cout << name.first << " " << name.last << '\n';
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Contacts contacts;
    contacts.add("First", "Last");
    Name name;
    name.first = "Foo";
    name.last = "Bar";

    contacts.add(name);
    contacts.display();
    return 0;
}
```

### Your comments could use some improvement

Your code doesn't contain many comments, and it would be helpful to see more of them. For example, it's not immediately obvious why there's a separate function to delete the head (`List::delete_head()`) vs. a different position (`List::delete_position()`). You should add comments to explain the requirements of the different functions. Even if you know why you have two different functions today, you might not remember if you look at the code again in a month.

Some of the comments you *do* have aren't very useful. For example:

```
while (temp != NULL)    // Loop through the list while the temporary node is not empty
```

That comment doesn't tell me anything that the actual `while (temp != NULL)` code hadn't already told me more succinctly.

Comment: Yes, I am required to implement a linked list as part of the assignment. Thank you for your feedback!